# Authorization error in google map in android: Refusing to reopen boot DEX '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar'

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have searched almost all the links here on `SO`, but still **my map** is not loading.

The `logcat` shows this message:

```
Refusing to reopen boot DEX '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar'
```

My package name is `"com.leonidas"` and Android manifest details are as follows:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.leonidas.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.leonidas.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: can you share your `AndroidManifest`, probably its related with some permissions or extend your `logcat` to see further details, maybe _simply your device does not support your `systrace`_

Comment: Did you ever fix this? It's not affecting my implementation but just an annoying error message